# Last rule in mod_rewrite returns 404 even though page exists

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htacccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+) /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/most-viewed/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+) /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC]

RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z]+) /news/categories/view-category.php?category=$1 [NC]
```

Everything works apart from the last rule. I have checked that all the pages exist, the newly added rule follows the same structure as the rules above which work, confused.

Do the variables need changing? Am I missing some code?

RESOLVED:

```
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/categories/?$ /news/categories.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/most-viewed/?$ /news/most-viewed.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /news/view-category.php?category=$1 [NC]


RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+) /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC]
```

I was missing the $ on the end.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is never a good error description. What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: I followed the same rewrite structure as the above rules which rewrite correctly and I receive a 404. Checked that the page exists and it does. Bit lost

Comment: Give an example of a URL that results in 404.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, and let me know if that works

```
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/most\-viewed/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /news/view-article.php?category=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^news/categories/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /news/categories/view-category.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```